# Concatenate Embedding layers

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to create a model which has words as inputs. Most of those words are in the glove word vector set (~50000). However, some of the frequent words are not (~1000). The question is, how do I concatenate the following two embedding layers to create one giant `Embedding` lookup table?

```
trained_em = Embedding(50000, 50, 
                       weights=np.array([word2glove[w] for w in words_in_glove]), 
                       trainable=False)
untrained_em = Embedding(1000, 50)
```

As far as I understand these are simply two lookup tables with same number of dimensions. So I'm hoping that there is a way to stack these two lookup tables.

**Edit 1:**
I just realised that this is probably going to be more than stacking `Embedding` layers because the input sequence would be a number from `0-50999`. However `untrained_em` above only expect a number from `0-999`. So perhaps a different solution is required.

**Edit 2:**
This is what I would expect to do in a numpy array representing the Embedding:

```
np.random.seed(42) # Set seed for reproducibility
pretrained = np.random.randn(15,3)
untrained = np.random.randn(5,3)
final_embedding = np.vstack([pretrained, untrained])

word_idx = [2, 5, 19]
np.take(final_embedding, word_idx, axis=0)
```

I believe the last bit can be done with something to do with `keras.backend.gather` but not sure how to put it all together.

Comment: So, you have 50,000 words from Glove and 1000 do not exist in Glove, and you want to learn embeddings for those 1000. Then, merge your new embeddings with the Glove embeddings. Right?

Comment: Correct. That's why I tried to use `trainable=False` on `trained_em` and `ceoncatenate` without much luck.

Comment: What is the error you get? Which line?

Comment: @Daniel, I didn't even get to the point of stacking because I wasn't quite sure how to. However' I added some more info. So probably concatenation of `Sequential` layers is not the way to go, unless I can stack them as simple matrices, which will solve the indexing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that I need to implement a custom layer. Which was implemented by tweaking the orignial `Embedding` class.

The two most important parts shown in the class below are `self.embeddings = K.concatenate([fixed_weight, variable_weight], axis=0)` and `out = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs)`. The first is hopefully self explanatory while the second picks out the relevant `input` rows from the `embeddings` table.

However, in the particular application that I'm working on, turns out that it works out better using an `Embedding` layer instead of the modified layer. Perhaps because the learning rate is too high. I will report back on this after I have experimented more.

```
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import keras.backend as K
from keras import initializers
import numpy as np

class Embedding2(Layer):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, fixed_weights, embeddings_initializer='uniform', 
                 input_length=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['dtype'] = 'int32'
        if 'input_shape' not in kwargs:
            if input_length:
                kwargs['input_shape'] = (input_length,)
            else:
                kwargs['input_shape'] = (None,)
        super(Embedding2, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.embeddings_initializer = embeddings_initializer
        self.fixed_weights = fixed_weights
        self.num_trainable = input_dim - len(fixed_weights)
        self.input_length = input_length

    def build(self, input_shape, name='embeddings'):
        initializer = initializers.get(self.embeddings_initializer)
        shape1 = (self.num_trainable, self.output_dim)
        variable_weight = K.variable(initializer(shape1), dtype=K.floatx(), name=name+'_var')

        fixed_weight = K.variable(self.fixed_weights, name=name+'_fixed')


        self._trainable_weights.append(variable_weight)
        self._non_trainable_weights.append(fixed_weight)

        self.embeddings = K.concatenate([fixed_weight, variable_weight], axis=0)

        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        if K.dtype(inputs) != 'int32':
            inputs = K.cast(inputs, 'int32')
        out = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs)
        return out

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if not self.input_length:
            input_length = input_shape[1]
        else:
            input_length = self.input_length
        return (input_shape[0], input_length, self.output_dim)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, my suggestion is to use only one Embedding layer (taking into consideration your indexing problem), and transfer the weights from the old layer to the new one.

So, what you're going to to in this suggestion is...

Create your new model with 51000 words:

```
inp = Input((1,)) 
emb = Embedding(51000,50)(inp)
out = the rest of the model.....

model = Model(inp,out)
```

Now take the embedding layer and give it the weights you had:

```
weights = np.array([word2glove[w] for w in words_in_glove])

newWeights = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
newWeights[:50000,:] = weights
model.layers[1].set_weights([newWeights])
```

This will give you a new embedding, larger than the previous one, with a great part of its weights already trained, and the remaining randomly initialized.

Unfortunately, you will have to let everything be trained.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, but I really want the first 50000 lines to be fixed. I think the solutions lies in using the backend, and creating a custom layer. I might be wrong here. +1 for offering a solution.